# get reverse list in c++

Tags: c++, tail-recursion

I am doing assignment for my college. I need to create recursive function.

My list_t interface contain following functions:

```
List Interface
The file recursive.h defines the type "list_t" and the following operations on lists:
// EFFECTS: returns true if list is empty, false otherwise
bool list_isEmpty​ (const list_t& list);
// EFFECTS: returns an empty list.
list_t list_make​ ();
// EFFECTS: given the list (list) make a new list consisting of
// the new element followed by the elements of the
// original list.
list_t list_make​ (int elt, const list_t& list);
// REQUIRES: list is not empty
// EFFECTS: returns the first element of list
int list_first​ (const list_t& list);
// REQUIRES: list is not empty
// EFFECTS: returns the list containing all but the first element of list
list_t list_rest​ (const list_t& list);
// MODIFIES: cout
// EFFECTS: prints list to cout.
void list_print​ (const list_t& list);
```

i need to create reverse function that is tail recursive without any global or static variable

i did come up with this function but it uses global variable

```
list_t l;
list_t reverse(list_t list){

    if(list.is_empty()==false){
        l=list_make(list.get_first_elt(),l);
        return reverse(list.get_rest_list());
    }else{
        return l;
    }
}
```

please Help..

here are rules that should be follows while writing function
● Each of these procedures must be tail recursive. For full credit, your routines must provide the correct result and provide an implementation that is tail recursive.
● In writing these functions, you may use only recursion and selection. You are NOT allowed to use goto, for, while, or do‐while
● No static or global variables
● If you define any helper functions, be sure to declare them " static ", so that they are not visible outside your program file. See the appendix for more information about tail recursion
and helper functions.

Comment: What do you exactly want? Please provide us with a problem to solve, otherwise we need to guess.

Comment: If you are trying to avoid a global variable, you can pass a reference parameter instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to get rid of the global variable, you can pass a reference parameter instead:

```
static list_t reverse_helper(list_t list,list_t &l){

    if(list.is_empty()==false){
        l=list_make(list.get_first_elt(),l);
        return reverse_helper(list.get_rest_list(),l);
    }else{
        return l;
    }
} 

list_t reverse(list_t list){
    list_t l;
    return reverse_helper(list,l);
}
```

Comment: thats the problem i cant change signature of function. i need to create reverse function with the help of list interface functions.

Comment: @ParthPatel: I had just provided a helper function, not change the original signature.  I've renamed my function to make that more clear.